Why is FPATH not listed in `env` output?
I'm running zsh (on MacOS) and I just learned about $fpath.
As usual, I then typed env to check it participating in my environment but to my surprise it was not there! Yet, $FPATH (and $fpath) is defined:
% echo $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions

% echo $FPATH
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions

Here's the variables printed out by env:
% env | sort | cut -d '=' -f 1
HOME
HOMEBREW_CELLAR
HOMEBREW_PREFIX
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
INFOPATH
LANG
LC_CTYPE
LOGNAME
MANPATH
OLDPWD
PATH
PWD
SHELL
SHLVL
SSH_AUTH_SOCK
TERM
TERM_PROGRAM
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
TERM_SESSION_ID
TMPDIR
USER
XPC_FLAGS
XPC_SERVICE_NAME
_
__CFBundleIdentifier

I have always relied on env to control my environment variables (in Bash), but apparently that is not the best option (not anymore at least)...
Should I be using a different command? Or how do I list all environment variables accessible to my current user/session?

maybe it's a shell variable, not an environment variable. Try with set instead of env

Yes, it is a shell variable and set does give me what I want. Thanks. Would you like to turn this comment into an answer @ArkadiuszDrabczyk?

Does this answer your question? Difference between shell variables which are exported and those which are not in bash

Hi @StephenKitt, thanks for the link. Although that Q/A discuss in the same topic, a different matter is addressed there: the impact of exporting variables. My issue here (or "ignorance") was spotted @Arkadiusz and @Kusalananda: the difference between environment and shell variables.

@Brandt that’s the same thing: a shell variable is an unexported variable, an environment variable is an exported variable. The use (or not) of export is what’s significant. But it is just a suggestion, I understand if you prefer the answer you were given here.

Variables used by the shell, like the ones you deal with here, or PROMPT, or HISTFILE, or IFS, do not need to be environment variables, i.e. they never need to be exported to the environment with export.
An exported variable will be visible to external utilities executed from the shell, such as the env utility, whereas variables that are not exported will not be visible to these utilities.
Variables the shell uses do not need to be exported to the environment since the shell already has access to their values.  Also, exporting them so that external utilities have access to their values will not be needed as it would only pollute the environment for those processes and, in certain rare cases, may cause interference.
If you want to see all shell variables, you may use the built-in set utility with no arguments.
